# (Wald's GR book) Isotropy implying constant curvature

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, symmetry, linear-algebra

**Context**

In Wald's GR book, p. 94 of chapter 5, he gives an argument for why isotropy and homogeneity implies constant curvature.

In summary, it goes like this: We can take the induced metric, $h_{ab}$, on the homogeneous hypersurface, $\Sigma$, and raise an index of the spatial Riemann tensor.
$$
R_{ab}^{\;\;\;cd}=h^{ce}R_{abe}^{\;\;\;\;d}.
$$
The resulting tensor, at a point $p \in \Sigma$ can be viewed as a linear operator (he calls it $L$) on the vector space of 2-forms. By the symmetries of the Riemann tensor, $L$ is a symmetric operator, and thus self-adjoint. Therefore, there is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $L$.

Wald then claims that if the eigenvalues of $L$ are distinct from each other, then isotropy is violated, since it would be possible to construct a preferred 2-form and, consequently, a preferred vector at $p$. The conclusion is: $L$ is a multiple of the identity operator.

**Question**

How does one construct such preferred vector from this information regarding the eigenvalues of $L$? Also, where do I find more information on this matter?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit: My attempt**

So I've been thinking hard on this and doing some research. I will write here an attempt, but I still appreciate any help or correction (if my attempt is wrong).

The sectional curvature, in abstract index notation, can be written as
$$
\kappa(\mbox{span}\{X,Y\})=\frac{g_{ae}X^{a}R_{\;\;bcd}^{e}Y^{b}X^{c}Y^{d}}{g_{bc}X^{b}X^{c}g_{de}Y^{d}Y^{e}-[g_{ab}X^{a}Y^{b}]^{2}}
$$
for orthogonal vectors $X$ and $Y$. We can rewrite it so as to make the operator $L$ more explicit,
$$
\kappa(\mbox{span}\{X,Y\})=\frac{X^{a}R_{ab}^{\;\;cd}\omega_{cd}Y^{b}}{g_{bc}X^{b}X^{c}g_{de}Y^{d}Y^{e}-[g_{ab}X^{a}Y^{b}]^{2}}
$$
Now, let's consider $X$ and $Y$ orthonormal vectors which decompose an eigenvector of $L$ (which are 2-forms), i.e for an eigenvector $\omega$,
$$
\omega_{ab} = X_{[a}Y_{b]}.
$$
I think it can be shown, under these conditions, that the sectional curvature defined above is the eigenvalue of $\omega$ - lets call it $\lambda_{XY}$. However, since the eigenvalues of $L$ are distinct, we can take other 2 orthonormal vectors $Z,W$ which decompose another eigenvector of $L$ (let's denote it $\gamma_{ab}$), and the corresponding sectional curvature will be its eigenvalue (let's denote it $\lambda_{ZW}\neq\lambda_{XY}$).

Now we define the vector
$$
v^a_{XY} = R^a_{\;\;bcd}Y^bX^cY^d.
$$
If space is isotropic, then there are isometries $f_{XZ}$ and $f_{YW}$ such that $(f_{XZ})_{*}X=Z$ and $(f_{YW})_{*}Y=W$. Let $h$ be the composition of these isometries. Then
$$
h_{*}v^a_{XY}=v^a_{ZW}.
$$
However, one may note that
$$
X_av^a_{XY} = \lambda_{XY} \neq \lambda_{ZW} = Z_av^a_{ZW}.
$$
Hence, $h$ isn't an isometry and, consequently, isotropy is violated.